# Multi-Step Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working with a modified version of the form found [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Creating-A-Modern-Multi-Step-Form-with-jQuery-CSS3.html). I simply want the form to not progress if the current tab's information is not correct. I modified the next buttons too (Changed type to submit, which still progresses form and calls my validation messages. I want users to be locked to the tab where things are not input correctly.)

```html
<input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified what sort of fields you have on your form. Assuming there are the regular ones like textboxes, checkboxes, etc, what you can do is

1. On load, disable the 'Next' button.
2. Bind a validator function to the change events for the fields requiring validation.
3. The validator function should check for all the conditions required for the tab and if they are all satisfied, enable the 'Next' button. Else, keep the button disabled.

Sample : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dxzsfLo/)

HTML :

```
<form id="input-form">
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="number" id="employee-id">
<input type="submit" name="Next" id="next-button" disabled>
</form>
```

JS (using jQuery) :

```
function validate() {
    if (validateName() && validateId()) {
    $('#next-button').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#next-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}

function validateName() {
    let name = $('#name').val();
    return name !== '' && !(/\d/.test(name));
}

function validateId() {
    let id = $('#employee-id').val()
    return id !== '' && !(/[a-z]/.test(id.toLowerCase()));
}

$('form > input').keyup(validate);
```